# Quantum phase transition in condensed matter

Tags: condensed-matter, hilbert-space, quantum-information, phase-transition, topological-phase

I want to know that, for any spin-chains in condensed matter Physics like X-Y spin model, Kitaev model 1-D only in which degenerate point is critical point. Is it necessary that the critical points has to be degeneracy points (gapless)? It means that at degeneracy point system becomes gapless it also shows Quantum Phase Transition in the spin-chain. In the point of view of quantum information, at the critical point (degenerate point) concurrence is maximum shows quantum phase transition in the spin-chain.
But my question is what if concurrence is maximum at not the degenerate points but at some other points. Then how will we find critical points and quantum phase transition,
also if concurrence is maximum at non-degenerate. Does it means our Hamiltonian has critical points which is gapped.?
My question is it necessary that Generate points has to be the critical points in any spin-chain condensed matter physics.
Critical point means that Quantum phase transition occurred at that point and degenerate point means gapless system.
Concurrence is a measure of entanglement
Which also can be use to study QPT in spin-chains.
Like for 1d Kitaev model at magnetic field is zero defined as critical point which also a degenerate point.
So you will see maximum value of concurrence at that point.
But what am saying in some cases other than Kitaev model at degenerate point concurrence value is zero but some other points which is non- degenerate point is shown to be maximum value.
So can someone please clear that?

Comment: Could you go into more detail about what you mean by degeneracy point, critical point, concurrence?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. In any case at a critical point the gap must close but the closing of the gap doesn't necessarily imply a critical point. In a symmetry broken phase there are exponentially small gaps (zero in the TDL) but they are not critical points